# How to use a lock_guard with try_lock_for

Tags: c++, boost, boost-mutex

I can use `boost::lock_guard` to acquire a lock on a `boost::mutex` object and this mechanism will ascertain that once the `boost::lock_guard` goes out of scope the lock will be released:

```
{
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(a_mutex);
  // Do the work
}
```

In this case, `a_mutex` will be released regardless of whether the code block was exited by an exception or not.

On the other hand, a `boost::timed_mutex` also supports a method `try_lock_for(period)`, e.g.

```
if(a_timed_mutex.try_lock_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1))) {
  // Do the work
  a_timed_mutex.unlock(); // <- This is needed!
} else {
  // Handle the acquisition failure
}
```

This code will not `unlock()` the `a_timed_mutex` if the `true` block of the `if` statement is exited with an exception.

**Question:** Boost (and, as far as I can see, neither the C++11 standard) do not seem to offer a variant of `lock_guard` that works with `try_lock()` or `try_lock_for(period)`. What is the "recommended" way or best practice to handle the second situation?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can create the lock guard after locking, telling it to adopt the lock:

```
if(a_timed_mutex.try_lock_for(boost::chrono::seconds(1))) {
  boost::lock_guard<boost::mutex> lock(a_timed_mutex, boost::adopt_lock_t());
  // Do the work
} else {
  // Handle the acquisition failure
}
```

The standard [lock_guard](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock_guard/lock_guard) also allows this.

Answer (score 0):

try unique_lock, unique_lock::try_lock_for()